# Keep significant zeros when switching column to character formatting in R

Tags: r, string-formatting

I am cleaning up data in R and would like to maintain numeric formatting when switching my column from numeric to character, specifically the significant zeros in the hundredths place (in example below). My input columns mostly begin as Factor data and the below is an example of what I am trying to do.

I'm sure there is a better way, just hoping for some folks with more knowledge than I to shed some light. Most questions online deal with leading zeros or formatting purely numeric columns, but the aspect of the "<" symbol in my data throws me for a loop as to the proper way of doing this.

```
df      = as.factor(c("0.01","5.231","<0.02","0.30","0.801","2.302"))
ind     = which(df %in% "<0.02")       # Locate the below detection value.
df[ind] <- NA                          # Substitute NA temporarily 
df      = as.numeric(as.character(df)) # Changes to numeric column
df      = round(df, digits = 2)        # Rounds to hundredths place
ind1    = which(df < 0.02)             # Check for below reporting limit values
df      = as.character(df)             # Change back to character column...
df[c(ind,ind1)] = "<0.02"              # so I can place the reporting limit back

> # RESULTS::
> df
[1] "<0.02" "5.23"  "<0.02" "0.3"   "0.8"   "2.3"
```

However, the 4th, 5th, and 6th values in the data are no longer reporting the zero in the hundredths place. What would be the proper order of operations for this? Perhaps changing the column back to character is incorrect? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: ---- Upon recommendations from hrbrmstr and Mike:
Thanks for the advice. I tried the following and they both result in the same problem. Perhaps there is another way I could be indexing/replacing values?

format, same problem:

```
#... code from above...
ind1    = which(df < 0.02)
df      = as.character(df)
df[!c(ind,ind1)] = format(df[!c(ind,ind1)],digits=2,nsmall=2)
> df
[1] "<0.02" "5.23"  "<0.02" "0.3 "  "0.8 "  "2.3 "
```

sprintf, same problem:

```
# ... above code from example ...
ind1 = which(df < 0.02)   # Check for below reporting limit values.
sprintf("%.2f",df)        # sprintf attempt.
[1] "0.01" "5.23" "NA"   "0.30" "0.80" "2.30"
df[c(ind,ind1)] = "<0.02" # Feed the symbols back into the column.
> df
[1] "<0.02" "5.23"  "<0.02" "0.3"   "0.8"   "2.3"  #Same Problem.
```

Tried a different way of replacing the values, and same problem.

```
# ... above code from example ...
> ind1    = which(df < 0.02)
> df[c(ind,ind1)] = 9999999
> sprintf("%.2f",df)
[1] "9999999.00" "5.23"       "9999999.00" "0.30"       "0.80"       "2.30" 
> gsub("9999999.00","<0.02",df)
[1] "<0.02" "5.23"  "<0.02" "0.3"   "0.8"   "2.3"  #Same Problem.
```

Comment: `?format` might help a bit

Comment: `?sprintf` might also be a good place to look - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pad it out with a `gsub` and a bit of regex...

```
df <- c("<0.02", "5.23", "<0.02", "0.3", "4",  "0.8",   "2.3")

gsub("^([^\\.]+)$", "\\1\\.00", gsub("\\.(\\d)$", "\\.\\10", df))

[1] "<0.02" "5.23"  "<0.02" "0.30"  "4.00"  "0.80"  "2.30"
```

The first `gsub` looks for a dot followed by a single digit and an end-of-string, and replaces the digit (the capture group `\\1`) with itself followed by a zero.  The second checks for numbers with no dots, and adds `.00` to the end.

Comment: What if the value is "4" when it should be "4.0", if only rounding at the tenths place? Is there a good link that you recommend for learning patterns in R?

Comment: There are several good introductions to regex out there.  I tend to use this one http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#ref.  Just remember to use double backslashes in R.